# Help me identify the name of a short story involving a man "waking up" to lizard people?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Last year I read a short story about a man who "wakes up" and realizes his world is ruled by lizard people. He gets really nervous that these lizard police will notice he has "woken up" so he tries to act normal but eventually the lizard police find him.

Does anyone know what story this is or is familiar enough to tell me the title and who wrote it? I have googled for hours but only "reptilian" conspiracy theories keep popping up.

Comment: Can you explain what part of this story is science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: Any idea how old the story is?

Comment: Is this the story in which the "awakened" man eventually reaches a TV station, quietly kills the reptilian news announcer, and croaks out an order to all who listen to "See us as we are and kill us" -- the beginning of the rebellion. But the awakened man, who was ordered to die at a set time, doesn't live to see the day, because his heart stops on cue. Well, if that's the case, it's probably from 1940-1970, but I don't recall the author or title.

Comment: Is "8:00 am" the story you were looking for? If so, you can accept that answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. Otherwise, let us know that we should look elsewhere.

Comment: @user14111 Yes, thanks, that's the one I described. The quotation actually is "George stood near him and said, imitating the alien croak, 'Wake up. Wake up. See us as we are and kill us!'" We'll see if this is also the story that davidnotspade23 wants to find.

Answer (score 7):

["Eight O'Clock in the Morning"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44474), a short story by [Ray Nelson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Nelson), first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, November 1963](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61342+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v025n05_1963-11_MadMaxAU/page/n73/mode/1up). You might have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?44474).

> At the end of the show the hypnotist told his subjects, "Awake."
>
> Something unusual happened.
>
> One of the subjects awoke all the way. This had never happened before. His name was George Nada and he blinked out at the sea of faces in the theatre, at first unaware of anything out of the ordinary. Then he noticed, spotted here and there in the crowd, the
> non-human faces, the faces of the Fascinators. They had been there all along, of course, but only George was really awake, so only George recognized them for what they were. He understood everything in a flash, including the fact that if he were to give any outward
> sign, the Fascinators would instantly command him to return to his former state, and he would obey.
>
> He left the theatre, pushing out into the neon night, carefully avoiding giving any indication that he saw the green, reptilian flesh or the multiple yellow eyes of the rulers of earth. One of them asked him, "Got a light buddy?" George gave him a light, then
> moved on.